# Highchart | Grouped stacked bar chart | Multiple stack labels

Tags: highcharts

Currently information is only the bottom edge of the bar. But, need to show information on both ends of the bars in stacked grouped bar chart.

I'm using stack labels to show information which has been aligned to show information on the bottom of the bar.

Requirement: Total of the stacked bar needs to be shown at top, whereas the category name needs to be remain at bottom.

I googled about the same, but no help.

Looking for solution. Thanks in advance.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mkdudeja/c5debf6g/6/

```js
$(function () {
    
    var options = {
      chart: {
        type: 'column',
        backgroundColor: '#f6f6f7'
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        symbolRadius: 2,
        itemStyle: {
          color: '#666',
          fontSize: '1.1rem',
          fontWeight: '400',
          fontFamily: '"Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif'
        }
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Overall', 'Timing', 'Impact'],
        labels: {
          y: 60,
          style: {
            color: '#333',
            fontSize: '1.3rem',
            fontWeight: '600',
            fontFamily: '"Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif'
          }
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        allowDecimals: false,
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        lineColor: 'transparent',
        minorTickLength: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
        labels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        stackLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          crop: false,
          overflow: 'none',
          y: 20,
          formatter: function () {
            const $this = this;
            return '$' + $this.total + 'M' +
              '<br>' + $this.stack;
          },
          style: {
            color: '#666',
            fontSize: '1.1rem',
            fontWeight: '400',
            fontFamily: '"Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif'
          }
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
          const $this = this;
          return '$' + $this.y + 'M' +
            '<br>' + $this.point.params.label;
        }
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          stacking: 'normal',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: 'white',
            formatter: function () {
              const $this = this;
              return (($this.y * 100) / $this.total).toFixed(1) + '%';
            }
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        type: undefined,
        name: 'Off Track',
        data: [
          {
            y: 12,
            params: {
              label: '12 initiatives'
            }
          },
          {
            y: 5,
            params: {
              label: '5 initiatives'
            }
          },
          {
            y: 4,
            params: {
              label: '4 initiatives'
            }
          }
        ],
        stack: 'Plan',
        color: '#b02c3b'
      }, {
        type: undefined,
        name: 'At Risk',
        data: [
          {
            y: 6,
            params: {
              label: '6 initiatives'
            }
          },
          {
            y: 9,
            params: {
              label: '9 initiatives'
            }
          },
          {
            y: 6,
            params: {
              label: '6 initiatives'
            }
          }
        ],
        stack: 'Plan',
        color: '#fbd155'
      }, {
        type: undefined,
        name: 'On Track',
        data: [
          {
            y: 10,
            params: {
              label: '10 initiatives'
            }
          },
          {
            y: 4,
            params: {
              label: '4 initiatives'
            }
          },
          {
            y: 7,
            params: {
              label: '7 initiatives'
            }
          }
        ],
        stack: 'Plan',
        color: '#35a761'
      }, {
        type: undefined,
        name: 'Off Track',
        data: [
          {
            y: 9,
            params: {
              label: '9 initiatives'
            }
          },
          {
            y: 6,
            params: {
              label: '6 initiatives'
            }
          },
          {
            y: 6,
            params: {
              label: '6 initiatives'
            }
          }
        ],
        stack: 'Forcast',
        color: '#b02c3b',
        showInLegend: false
      }, {
        type: undefined,
        name: 'At Risk',
        data: [
          {
            y: 5,
            params: {
              label: '5 initiatives'
            }
          },
          {
            y: 6,
            params: {
              label: '6 initiatives'
            }
          },
          {
            y: 10,
            params: {
              label: '10 initiatives'
            }
          }
        ],
        stack: 'Forcast',
        color: '#fbd155',
        showInLegend: false
      }, {
        type: undefined,
        name: 'On Track',
        data: [
          {
            y: 7,
            params: {
              label: '7 initiatives'
            }
          },
          {
            y: 6,
            params: {
              label: '6 initiatives'
            }
          },
          {
            y: 8,
            params: {
              label: '8 initiatives'
            }
          }
        ],
        stack: 'Forcast',
        color: '#35a761',
        showInLegend: false
      }]
    };
    

    $('#container').highcharts(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place stack labels at top by default and in the `render` event move the stack names to the bottom:

```
    chart: {
        ...,
        events: {
            render: function() {
                var labels = this.yAxis[0].stackTotalGroup.element.children;

                for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                    labels[i].children[1].setAttribute('y', 275);
                    labels[i].children[3].setAttribute('y', 275);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9raLyx85/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: Thanks, Works as expected. Just one question, why the 'y' attribute has been set to 275? What's the logic behind that?

Comment: Hi @Manish Kumar, That is the `y` position of the label. You can try to change it to see a different result. You can also calculate it based on the height of the chart.

Comment: Hi, This doesn't works in IE. Tested on iE11. Can you look into that please?

Comment: Hi @Manish Kumar, You need to use `childNodes` insted of `children` in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/en9f58yr/

Comment: I tried that too, its failing for childNodes too. Can you update the jsFiddle for IE?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, Did you get a chance to get this resolved on IE? For me, its still failing.

Comment: Hi @Manish Kumar, I tested the example with used `childNodes` on IE 11 and it works correctly.